# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 when import LWIMKIT.framwork

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, duplicates, unrecognized-selector

Project use swift. And after importing this LWIMKIT.framwork, I faced duplicate symbols problem.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDTTYLoggerColorProfile in:
    /Users/Arain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Taoji-aldpdybccvcoflbbrtplhgqzroqp/Build/Intermediates/Taoji.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Taoji.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DDTTYLogger.o
    /Users/Arain/Desktop/ARAIN_PRO/develop/Taoji/LWIMKIT.framework/LWIMKIT(DDTTYLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDTTYLoggerColorProfile in:
    /Users/Arain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Taoji-aldpdybccvcoflbbrtplhgqzroqp/Build/Intermediates/Taoji.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Taoji.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DDTTYLogger.o
 /Users/Arain/Desktop/ARAIN_PRO/develop/Taoji/LWIMKIT.framework/LWIMKIT(DDTTYLogger.o)
...
ld: 123 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I delete -ObjC in other linker flags, this can be solved, but when compiling, another problem shows which is unrecognized selector sent to class, I guess this framework define some variables or function whose name same as system.

Please help me!!!

Comment: I had the similar problem. You can see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34043980/1836420):